# CSS on hover color change dose not effect i tag

Tags: html, css

I created div that contains 2 tags: span and i.
I tried to add on hover on the div that will change the color and cursor but on the i tag the color doesn't change.

```css
.example {
    margin: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
}
.example i {
    border: solid #8690ab;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    line-height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.example span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #8690ab;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}

.example:hover, .example:hover i, .example:hover span{   
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #a9afc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <span>text</span>
  <i className="arrowdown"></i>
</div>
```

How to also change the color of the i tag?
There is better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color tag only changes the color of the text in the tag. Since there's no text, nothing will happen. You can try changing the border-color, if that's what is required:

```
.example:hover, .example:hover i, .example:hover span{   
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #a9afc0;
    color: #a9afc0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.example {
      margin: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
}
.example i {
    border: solid #8690ab;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    line-height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.example span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #8690ab;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}

.example:hover, .example:hover i, .example:hover span{   
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #4287f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #4287f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <span>text</span>
  <i className="arrowdown"></i>
</div>
```